# [Error]_Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm learning to setup Webpack to my React project. Then, I met an error on the Babel setting step when I run this command

> npx webpack --config webpack.config.js

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:33:19)
at resolveStandardizedName (...\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:111:7)      
at resolvePreset (...\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:59:10)
at loadPreset (...\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:78:20)
at loadPreset.next (<anonymous>)
at createDescriptor (...\project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:187:16)       
at createDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
at step (...\project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
at evaluateAsync (...\project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:291:5)
```

---

More detail, I have some code lines:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                "targets": "defaults"
              }],
              '@babel/preset-react'
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "antd": "^4.17.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this problem and What is the point of caution?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from an incorrect .babelrc file, please look at it closer - you are defining babel to use "2015" preset but your dependencies point that you are using "@babel/preset-env".

The correct replacement for "2015" is "@babel/preset-env" in your case. Read about it more:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "react"]
}
```

Comment: It completely solved the error when I ran `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`. But I still cannot compile to `start` instruction with other error. Thank you for your help! @zonni

Comment: Configuration webpack is really a problem with me at this time...